# Distance between two particles traveling the same curve

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, curves

I have two particles simultaneously traveling a $\mathcal{C}^1$ curve $\gamma \colon [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$.

The first particle's position at time $t$ is $p_1(t) = \gamma\left( \phi(t) \right)$, where $\phi \in \mathcal{C}^1\left( \left[0, 1\right] \right)$ is strictly increasing onto $[0, 1]$.

The second particle's position at time $t$ is simply $p_2(t) = \gamma\left( t \right)$.

I would like to integrate the squared distance between the particles over the period of travel.

$$ I = \int_0^1 \left( p_1(t) - p_2(t) \right)^2 \, dt $$

Can I bound $I$ in terms of $\phi^\prime$ and say, the arclength of $\gamma$? Or the $L^2$-norm of $\gamma$?

I think I should be able to get something of the form

$$I =   \int_0^1 ( \phi^\prime (x) - 1 )^2 \gamma'(x)^2 \, d x $$
$$ \text{or } \ \ \  I = \int_0^1 ( \phi^\prime (x) - 1 )^2 \gamma(x)^2 \, dx $$
modulo a change of variables somewhere.

Comment: integrate **the square of** the distance...

Comment: Another correction, on the first line $\gamma \colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R^2}$ (or $\mathbb{R^3}$ ?).

Comment: @JeanMarie Nope, just $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: Surprising, it is not what is usually called a (parameterized) curve !

Comment: So your curve is "flattened" onto the $x$ axis ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes you could think of it like that.  Imagine the particles are in a straight tube, and they are tracing out some predefined sequence of steps left and right.

Comment: Is $\gamma$ 1-1? Also, since you are integrating distance squared, not distance, please say so.

Comment: @zhw. No $\gamma$ is not $1$-$1$.  In fact it will be a closed curve, but I do not believe this is relevant for the problem.

Comment: By using the mean value theorem and some integral manipulations you can find the bound $I\leq\|\gamma'\|_\infty^2\int_0^1(\phi'(t)-1)^2\operatorname dt$, where $\|f\|_\infty:=\sup_{0\leq x\leq1]}|f(x)|$. If that's useful I can tell you how.

Comment: @OskarLimka Yes that's essentially what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2):

By fundamental theorem of calculus you have
$$p_1(t)-p_2(t)=\gamma(\phi(t))-\gamma(t)=\int_t^{\phi(t)}\gamma'(z)\operatorname dz.$$
From here you have many options, for example using Cauchy--Bunyakovskii--Schwarz you may write
$$|p_1(t)-p_2(t)|^2\leq|\phi(t)-t|\int_t^{\phi(t)}|\gamma'(z)|^2\operatorname dz$$
and note that for $t\geq0$ (assuming $\phi(0)=0$, but you can drop this with a bit of work)
$$
|\phi(t)-t|^2=\left|\int_0^t\phi'(\tau)-1\operatorname d\tau\right|^2\leq t\int_0^t|\phi'(\tau)-1|^2\operatorname d\tau.
$$
In both inequalities you can "get rid" of many $t$s at the cost of more generous gaps, by noting that $0\leq t,\phi(t)\leq1$.  You can then arrange things to your liking.

Sorry for not being more precise, but if you clarify what you want I may be able to help you more.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your help!